Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec
I am converting paper from IEEE format to springer nature format.
I am facing the problem with \vec{b}. In IEEE format, it was like b with arrow on top, but in the springer template, it looks like bold 'b'.
Is am doing some error because overleaf is giving a warning: Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.? My knowledge of latex is very basic.
The detail of libraries I am using is:
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}  

Also, one side question: Some how the springer template wastes a lot of space between figures, after headings and subheadings. The maximum pages I can use for the paper is 14 and I tried my level best to squeeze things, but I am still on 15 pages. What generally people do in these situations. My knowledge of latex is very basic.Any idea would be great help.
Edit1
I am editing the question so that the code can be tested.
Below is the link for the template.
Template Link
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}  
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title}
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
\institute{blank space \and
blank space
\email{blank}\\
\url{blank} \and
blank\\
\email{\{abc,lncs\}@un.d}}
\maketitle              
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Vector is not displayed correctly  $\vec{b}$
\end{document}

On compiling the above code, I am getting below two warnings.
Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.

 
‪/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty‬
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

 
‪/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty


It is a good question to ask with some components presented for consideration. What remains missing is a segment of the work mentioned that would reproduce the \vec issue (and maybe the space after a picture). If this was provided (a sample document section that produces only the errors mention in the question) help beyond " maybe try this " could be provided.

If I make your code snippet minimally compilable by prefixing the instruction \documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl} and affixing the instructions \begin{document} $\vec{b}$ \end{document}, I am unable to generate the amsmath warning message you say you are getting. Moreover, I get "b" with an arrow on top, not a bold letter b as you assert in your writeup. Do please provide more information about what you're doing.

Thank you @Mico for the response. I have edited the question. Please review the question.

I assume there's a reason for why you're switching from the IEEEtran class to the llncs class. If that's the case, I would strongly discourage you from tinkering with the new defaults for macros such as \vec.

It is just the requirement of the conference. Earlier, they asked paper in IEEE format. For publishing they want in springer format. I donot have deep knowledge of latex. My knowledge is just putting things in the template. Trying to keep things same as much as possible adhering strictly to the template format. If springer considers \vec{b} as bold b, then also fine. @Mico

You need to pass orivec to the class.
\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}

Leaving the rest unchanged, I get

